# How to calculate execution time of a python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, execution-time

I am calling a function to download a file from sharepoint and upload to sql server database.
I am logging the information success and failure in a table. how can i calculate total time that takes during the execution of this function?

like:

```
start_time=datetime.now()
function call 
end_time=datetime.now()
total=end_time-start_time
```

please suggest the working query, i am running out of time.

Comment: why aren't you just using the example you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get it done:

**Code:**

```py
from datetime import datetime

st = datetime.now()

#call your function here

et=datetime.now()
print('\nTotal time for execution : {}'.format(et-st).split(".")[0])
```

**Output:**

```py
Total time for execution : 0:00:00
```